# macOS/ Xcode / Swift 3, how can I have a storyboard scene inside a NSScrollView?

Tags: macos, swift3, storyboard, scrollview

I am new to storyboards and just learning swift. My document based app has a main document view where all the action is (user mouse clicks, keyDown, etc). It's size can vary based on either user menu command or model state changes. It also has subviews that may come and go. This needs to be the document view of an NSScrollview.

This document view needs its own view controller.

Starting with the main storyboard if I add a scroll view to the main view controller view, I can set my custom view to be the document view. But there doesn't seem to be anyway to give it it's own view controller, within the storyboard paradigm.

Previously, (under objective c, if that matters), I was able to create my document view and it's view controller in a XIB, then in code assign this document view to the NSScrollview's document view.

Presumably, I could still do this in code in Xcode 8/Swift 3, but isn't there a way to do it with storyboards?

**Added Later**:  I seem to get close to what I want by replacing the scroll view's document view with a container view. I'm using a centering clip view, and apparently the container view cannot have constraints, or it defeats the centering!

I can then drag a new view controller onto the container view. The new view controller and it's view can be my custom view controller and it's custom view.

This looks like it will work OK, so far, but it seems a bit of a kludge to me. Is this the standard way to embed a custom view controller with its view in an NSScrollView?